# step() and multiple interactions in R

Tags: r

I want to use the step() function (or a similar one if you think it would be better) to work out the best model and accounting for interactions.
I have created the dummy dataset.

```
pos.neg<- c(1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
var1<- c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE)
var2<- c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE)
var3<- c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)
var4<- c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)   
var5<- c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)
var6<- c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)
var7<- c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE)
fin.bin<- data.frame(pos.neg,var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6)
```

This is what I have done:

```
base.bin<- glm(pos.neg~1, data=fin.bin, family=binomial)
var<- names(fin.bin)
var<- var[var!="pos.neg"]
text<- paste( 'pos.neg ~ ', paste(var, collapse= "+"))
text2<- paste(var,collapse="*")
text3<- paste(text,"+",text2)
f<- as.formula(text3)
bestmodel.bin<- step(base.bin,scope=list(upper=f,lower=~1), direction="both",data=fin.bin)
summary(bestmodel.bin)
```

While I understand that all variables are included by "text" I am not sure if also all possible interactions between the 6 explanatory variables are checked in step() the way I defined "text2" (these should be factorial(6)=720 interactions I guess?).

Is there a tidier way to write this or another function that would find the best model to fit the outcome variable pos.neg verifying which variables and also their interactions are best to be included?

Many thanks
Marco

Comment: For what purpose are you fitting this model? That is, are you interested in predicting the response, or in figuring out if each variable/interaction is associated with the response? If you're sure you're doing something reasonable for your situation, this is probably the right forum to get help with the coding, but for assistance in deciding what to do (ie, if step is reasonable at all), the stats.stackexchange forum is probably more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you @Aaron. I am trying to figure out if each variable is associated with the response (the response is a clinical sign, each variable is a drug administered/not administered prior to the development of the clinical sign). I will then look at the significance and calculate my odd ratios for the variable included in the most appropriate model with the best AIC. I am pretty sure this is the correct way to do this as I have done it before but had less variables and could sort it out manually. I can ask stats.stackexchange but I was just hoping to automate the process to be faster! Cheers

Comment: Got it. The concern is that whether or not terms are included or not in a stepwise model is not a great way to determine which terms are significantly associated with the response. See for example this great answer http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/3601 to a poor question.